# trigger("change") on label click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a `change` event on an input whenever the corresponded label gets clicked. Here's what I tried in jQuery:

```
$(document).on("mouseup touchend", "label", function() {
  $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).trigger("change");
});

$(".my_example_input").on("change", function() {
  alert("Change called!");
});
```

Comment: which labels? Please be more descriptive

Comment: The code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3dkna9xz/. If you are having issues we need to see a more complete example which demonstrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this,hope it helps.I guess this is what you are expecting,thanks

```js
$('label,#checkbox_id').click(function(e){
    $('.my_example_input').trigger('change')
 
})

 $('.my_example_input').change(function(e){
     console.log('input has been changed')
   
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" value="value">
<label for="checkbox_id">Text</label>

<input class='my_example_input'>
```